# Interesting Powers Of 2 - algorithm/ Math (from Hackerrank ACM APC)

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I came across a problem from a recent competition. 
I was unable to figure out a solution, and no editorial for the question is yet available.

> [Question Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/apc/challenges/interesting-powers-of-two)

I am quoting the problem statement here also in case the link doesn't work.

Find the number of integers n which are greater than or equal to A and less than or equal to B (A<= n <=B) and the **decimal representation of 2^n ends in n**.

**Ex:** 2^36 = 68719476736  which ends in “36”.

**INPUT**

The first line contains an integer T i.e. number of test cases. T lines follow, each containing two integers A and B.

**Constraints**

```
1 <= T <= 10^5

A<=B

A,B <= 10^150
```

**OUTPUT**

Print T lines each containing the answer to the corresponding testcase.

---

**Sample Input**

```
2
36 36
100 500
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
0
```

Comment: at the very least you should have been able to come up with a brute force solution. I don't see enough effort.

Comment: The question as it is now belongs to the http://math.stackexchange.com/ network.

Comment: @Erbureth in fact I believe it is for the programming competitions stackexchange site but it is still in commitment phase.

Comment: Check out modular exponentiation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev If you're talking about [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52595/competitive-programming), it's been closed.

Comment: @Dukeling yeap the very one. Too sad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can try solving these problems by finding some pattern in the output. Our team got this problem accepted at the contest. Our approach was to find a general pattern in the values that satisfy the criteria. If you print the first few such digits, then you will find the following pattern

```
    36
   736
  8736
 48736
948736
```

Thus the next number after 948736 should be of 7 digits and can be any one of 1948736, 2948736, 3948736, 4948736, 5948736, 6948736, 7948736, 8948736, 9948736. Thus check which value is valid and you have the next number. Continuing in this fashion you can back yourself to get all the 150 numbers.

But there is a problem here. There will be some numbers that do not immediately follow from the previous number by appending '1' to '9'. To counter this you can now start appending values from 10 to 99 and now check if there is a valid number or not. If there is still no valid number, then again try appending numbers from 100 to 999.

Now employing this hack, you will get all the 137 values that satisfy the criterion given in the question and easily answer all the queries. For example, working java code that implements this is shown [here](http://ideone.com/NLNkt4). It prints all the 137 values.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
        new Solution().run();
    }

    void run()throws java.lang.Exception{
        BigInteger[] powers = new BigInteger[152];
        powers[0] = one;
        for(int i=1; i<=150; i++){
            powers[i] = powers[i-1].multiply(ten);
        }
        BigInteger[] answers = new BigInteger[152];
        answers[2] = BigInteger.valueOf(36);
        answers[3] = BigInteger.valueOf(736);

        int last = 3;
        for(int i=4; i<=150; i++){
            int dif = i-last;
            BigInteger start = ten.pow(dif-1);
            BigInteger end = start.multiply(ten);
            while(start.compareTo(end) < 0){
                BigInteger newVal = powers[last].multiply(start);
                newVal = newVal.add(answers[last]);
                BigInteger modPow = pow(two, newVal, powers[i]);
                if(modPow.equals(newVal)){
                    answers[i] = newVal;
                    System.out.println(answers[i]);
                    last = i;
                    break;
                }
                start = start.add(one);
            }
        }
    }


    BigInteger pow(BigInteger b, BigInteger e, BigInteger mod){
        if(e.equals(zero)){
            return one;
        }
        if(e.mod(two).equals(zero)){
            BigInteger x = pow(b, e.divide(two), mod);
            x = x.multiply(x).mod(mod);
            return x;
        }else{
            BigInteger x = pow(b, e.divide(two), mod);
            x = x.multiply(x).mod(mod);
            x = x.multiply(two).mod(mod);
            return x;
        }
    }

    BigInteger ten = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
}
```

Comment: According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760141/interesting-powers-of-2-algorithm-math-from-hackerrank-acm-apc#comment34699818_22760385), you needn't check for all of 10-999, rather just 10,20,30,...,100,200,300,....

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, trying to append 100, 200, 300, ... will solve the problem. I have checked this with the 137 generated numbers.

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks. And just one more thing, can you think of a way to do it without Big Int ? I mean by modular exponentiation or somewhat similiar such tha our number fits within 10^20?

Comment: I think we must use BigInteger. Because we have to look at the last 100 or more digits. You can ask other C++ coders what they do to handle problems on BigInts.

Answer (score 8):

As often happens on programming competitions I have come up with an heuristics I have not proven, but seems plausible. I have written a short program to find the numbers up to 1000000 and they are:

```
36
736
8736
48736
948736
```

Thus my theory is the following - each consecutive number is suffixed with the previous one and only adds one digit. Hope this will set you on the right track for the problem. Note that if my assumption is right than you only need to find 150 numbers and finding each consecutive number requires checking 9 digits that may be added.

A general advice for similar problems - always try to find the first few numbers and think of some relation.

Also often it happens on a competition that you come up with a theory like the one I propose above, but have no time to prove it. You can't afford the time to prove it. Simply hope you are right and code.

EDIT: I believe I was able to prove my conjecture above(in fact I have missed some numbers -see end of the post). First let me point out that as v3ga states in a comment the algorithm above works up until `75353432948736` as no digit can be prepended to make the new number "interesting" as per the definition you give. However I completely missed another option - you may prepend some number of 0 and then add a non-zero digit.

I will now proof a lemma:

**Lemma:** if a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> is an interesting number and n is more than 3, then a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> also is interesting.

Proof:
2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> = 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup>*2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup>

Now I will prove that 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup>*2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> is comparable to 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> modulo 10<sup>n-1</sup>.

To do that lets prove that 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup>*2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> - 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> is divisible by 10<sup>n-1</sup>.

2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup>*2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> - 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> = 
2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> * (2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> - 1)
a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> is more than n-1 for the values we consider.

Thus all that's left to prove to have 10<sup>n-1</sup> dividing the difference is that 5<sup>n-1</sup> divides 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> - 1.
For this I will use Euler's theorem:

2<sup>phi(5<sup>n-1</sup>)</sup> = 1 (modulo 5<sup>n-1</sup>).

Now phi(5<sup>n-1</sup>) = 4*(5<sup>n-2</sup>) and for n >= 3 4*(5<sup>n-2</sup>) will divide a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup>(actually even solely 10<sup>n - 1</sup>).

Thus  2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> gives remainder 1 modulo 5<sup>n-1</sup> and so  5<sup>n-1</sup> divides 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> - 1.

Consequently 10<sup>n-1</sup> divides 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> * (2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> - 1) and so the last n - 1 digits of 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> and 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> are the same.

Now as a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> is interesting the last n digits of 2<sup>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> are a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> and so the last n-1 digits of 2<sup>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub>...a<sub>n</sub></sup> are a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> and consequently a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> is also interesting. QED.

Use this lemma and you will be able to solve the problem. Please note that you may also prepend some zeros and then add a non-zero number.

Comment: Wow, excellent heuristics. But there's some problems after the 13th number. There's no number after `75353432948736` in this sequence. i.e. No digit from `1-9` when appended to left of that number will give a number with the property that `2^n % (10^ number of digits in n) = n`

Comment: @v3ga nice observation. So my conjecture is not true. Now we have two options: either no number larger than 75353432948736 meets the condition, or I am missing some numbers. I bet on option 2. Still I think it is worth a submit to check if these are really all numbers that meet the condition

Comment: Did you come up with the theory by brute force on smaller numbers or some mathematical property?

Comment: I mention that in my answer - brute force for small numbers. That is the way people usually go on an actual competition. I am currently trying to come up with some proof at least for some part of my statement.

Comment: I believe this should go as a comment,
a(n+1) is a suffix of 2^a(n) formed by a non-zero digit followed by a number of zeros and a(n). Where a(n) is the nth term of the sequence.
Source : http://oeis.org/A064541

Comment: @Mod Grt. So if none of 1-9 can be added, append a 0 and continue.

Comment: @v3ga <at>Grt proof of my statement added.

Comment: Your lemma still allows for the possibility that there will be multiple numbers of base-10 length k that are interesting, and then the search for increasing k will have to branch into the multiple possibilities that are interesting. A stronger statement would be that there is at most one possible value for a1 (possibly zero).

Comment: @user2566092 yes, but as I have brute forced all numbers up to 1000000 I know which are the last 6 digits. From there on we have to search for a number that starts with some non-zero digit has some zeros and ends with `75353432948736`. This can be done in linear times an exponentiation.

Comment: Nicely explained. +1 definately. You are good at math, the proving went over my head :P

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thanks for the proof. Also, please have a look [at this code](http://ideone.com/ydVgtf).

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting property. During the contest, I found that 36 was the only number under 500 checking with python...
The property is : 2^36 last two digits are 36, last three digits are 736, so next number is 736. 2^736 has last three digits as 736, and next number is 8376...

And [the series](http://oeis.org/A064541) is : 36 , 736 , 8736 , 48736 , 948736 ...

And then started with BigInt class in C++.
But alas there was no time, and 4th problem wasn't solved. But after the contest, we did it in python.
here's link : [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/8dTX66)

```
def powm(i):
j = 10
a = 1
while i:
    if i % 2:
        a = a * j
    i /= 2
    j *= j
return a


def power(n, i):
    m = powm(i)
    y = 1
    x = 2
    while n:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            y = y * x % m
        x = x * x % m
        n /= 2
    return y

mylist = []
mylist.append(power(36, 2))
n = mylist[0]
print(n)
for i in range(3, 170):
    p = power(n, i)
    print p
    if p != n:
        mylist.append(p)
        n = p

t = input()
while t:
    x = raw_input().split(" ")
    a = int(x[0])
    b = int(x[1])
    i = 0
    #while i <= 150:
        #print mylist[i]
        #i += 1
#print power(8719476736,14)

while mylist[i] < a:
    i += 1
ans = 0
while mylist[i] <= b:
    i += 1
    ans += 1
print ans
t -= 1
```

Comment: @anubhav - Yup asati told me the property but the same prob, how to do it in C++

Comment: My team was implementing BigInt , but we ran out of time.

Answer (score 0):

The final digits start to repeat after 20 increments. So for any n with the final digit 1, the final digit of the answer will be 2. So most values of n can be eliminated immediately.

2^1 = 2 
2^21 = 2097152
2^101 = 2535301200456458802993406410752

2^2 = 4
2^22 = 4194304
2^42 = 4398046511104

In fact only two possibilities share a final digit:

2^14 = 16384
2^16 = 65536

2^34 = 17179869184
2^36 = 68719476736

If n is 14+20x or 16+20x, then it might work, so you'll need to check it. Otherwise, it cannot work.

Comment: In fact a lot of value will be eliminated but still not enough - the limit is to 10^150. My presumption is that in total 150 numbers up to 10^150 meet the condition as I suggest in my answer. I have not proven it though

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good with such problems. But modular exponentiation appears to be key in your case.
Repeat for all n in the range A to B:
 1. Find k, the no of digits in n. This can be done in O(logn)
 2. Find 2^n (mod 10^k) **using modular exponentiation** and check if it is equal to n. This'll take O(n) time. (actually, O(n) multiplications)

**EDIT**
Actually, don't repeat the whole process for each n. Given 2^n (mod 10^k), we can find 2^(n+1) (mod 10^k) in constant time. Use this fact to speed it up further

**EDIT - 2**
This doesn't work for such large range.

Comment: This will definitely not work. In the worst case you need to check 10^150 numbers, which no matter how efficiently implemented will finish when the universe is long gone.